# Websphere to ActiveMQ Artemis not connecting

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am configuring connectivity to ActiveMQ Artemis using core JMS client. The simplest thing in the WebSphere, but WebSphere is not connecting to it:

[image]

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Are you receiving any particular error messages?

Answer (score 1):

At the very least your URL is incorrect. You're using syntax from the OpenWire JMS client shipped with ActiveMQ Classic. Use something like this instead:

```
(tcp://ppr-t24-qve-01:61616,tcp://ppr-t24-qve-02:61616)?ha=true&reconnectAttempts=-1
```

Comment: this way is not working still websphere is not connecting to artemis mq. I will try the another way its that work i will share the feedback